# Get count of rows for pagination

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm implementing pagination and would like to get the count of all records before setting the max results. This is my original query:

```
String queryString = "SELECT pm FROM FriendComputer pm LEFT JOIN FETCH pm.computer m WHERE pm.friendAccount.id = :friendId "
org.hibernate.query.Query q = session().createQuery(queryString, FriendComputer.class).setParameter(
            "friendId", friendId);

 q.setFirstResult(0);
 q.setMaxResults(25);
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
String queryString = "SELECT count(*), pm FROM FriendComputer pm LEFT JOIN FETCH pm.computer m WHERE pm.friendAccount.id = :friendId "
org.hibernate.query.Query q = session().createQuery(queryString).setParameter(
            "friendId", friendId);
```

Here I want to extract the first result for total count of rows. However the query returns an Object[] and I don't know how to extract the results. I want to be able to set the first result and max results just like before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this can't be done. You have to issue 2 queries.